# Python best practice for importing grandparent module in parent and child modules

Tags: python, module, python-module

Let's say I have module `child`:

```
# child.py

import numpy as np
import parent

parent.do_stuff(A = np.array([1,2,3]))
```

Then in `parent`:

```
# parent.py

# Should I import numpy here?

def do_stuff(A):
    print A.T
```

My question is, do I import `numpy` in `parent`, even though I know it should not be used as a standalone module? I prefer to re-`import` `numpy` because it is clear that `A` is a `numpy` `array` rather than a Python `list` but it also doesn't seem DRY.

Comment: Will you be *documenting* what `A` is expected to be?

Comment: Yeah. Is that my answer?

Comment: Depends. If you really only want array arguments that may suffice. But note that you can't check e.g. `isinstance` or convert non-array arguments without access to `numpy` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-import numpy where you suggest in `parent.py`. For justification I refer you to PEP 20:

> Explicit is better than implicit
>
> Simple is better than complex

Certainly re-importing numpy makes it clear what you expect A to be. The following is even more explicit that A should be a numpy matrix:

```
# parent.py

import numpy an np

def do_stuff(A):
    print np.transpose(A)
```